# the esper events do not perform aggregation logic correctly

Tags: esper

I have a tuple:

```
public class mytuple
{
    private int status;

    private int userid;
    private int location;

    private int count1;
    private int count2;

    // corresponding getter settrs included.
}
```

I create two esper statements EPL:

```
select mytuple.userid as userid, sum(count1) as count1, sum(count2) as count2
from eventStream where mytuple.status = -1
group by userid, location;

and another EPL statement:

select mytuple.userid as userid, sum(count1) as count1, sum(count2) as count2
from eventStream where mytuple.status = 1
group by userid, location;
```

The event streams are registered inside the configuration.

The issue i am facing is , on the two events being sent out.. one as status= -1 and another as status = +1, I get an incremental count of +2 on first EPL statement.

However, if only one event is being sent, the streams work perfectly.
Is there any thing that I am missing here??

Assuming the fact that I have a seperate listener to the Esper view which was created.

Comment: Status is not being aggregated by these statements, count1 and count2 are.  What are the values of count1 and count2 for the test events?

Answer (score 0):

Best to run this by the Esper user mailing list, as described in http://esper.codehaus.org/about/esper/mailinglist.html
Create a small test case and send that along, make sure you use a recent version.

For filtering put the conditions in parenthesis, which is the preferred notation:

select ....from eventStream(mytuple.status = 1) ....